# Reuse conditional statements in sub-classes.

Tags: java, abstract, dry, abstract-methods

I have below classes:

```
public abstract class Parent {

    public abstract boolean checkName(String str);
}


public class Child1 extends Parent {

    public static final String NAME = "CHILD1";

    @Override
    public boolean checkName(String str) {
        //check input validity:
        if (!NAME.equals(str)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("some thing");
        }
        //...
    }
}


public class Child2 extends Parent {

    public static final String NAME = "CHILD2";

    @Override
    public boolean checkName(String str) {
        //check input validity:
        if (!NAME.equals(str)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("some thing");
        }
        // ...
    }

}
```

You can see `check input validity` parts of `checkName` methods in both classes are same.I know there is no way to move this joint part to abstract `checkName` method of parent,but is there a way to avoid this repeating?

Comment: Make your parent class not abstract... and implement this method there.

Comment: To me `checkName` doesn't look like that you should inherit .. To me it looks more like utility class method ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might switch things around so that the `checkName()` function is concrete in the `Parent` class, have it do the input validity check, then invoke some abstract method that your child classes implement to do the rest of the processing.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer. This is the crux of the solution which wouldn't take long for someone to realize. What's interesting is the intricacies involved. How do you expose minimal functionality to the client? How do you come up with a solution that can be used for checking a condition on any `String` and not just the `name`? It's easier said than done and in all fairness, the other answers do a better job in explaining how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Do it in regular way. Create real method "check input validity" in abstract class and use it within any method of your real classes.
That's the regular way and it's pretty often used for refactoring.

Also having one static variable for all classes has no sense.
Here is what, I think, you need:

```
public abstract class Parent {

    public String NAME;

    public abstract boolean checkName(String str);

    public void checkInputValidity(String str) {
        if (!NAME.equals(str)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("some thing");
        }
    }
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
    public Child1() {
        NAME = "CHILD1";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkName(String str) {
        checkInputValidity(str);
        // ...
        return true;
    }
}

class Child2 extends Parent {

    public Child2() {
        NAME = "CHILD2";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkName(String str) {
        // check input validity:
        checkInputValidity(str);
        // ...
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's stopping the client code from calling `checkInputValidity` (since it's `public`) and go against the intention of your API? What happens when a subclass wants to have a condition on the `address` field rather than the `name` field. See my answer for a more flexible approach.

Answer (score 2):

[David's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1156554/david) answer covers the crux of the solution but does not cover intricacies of the solution. The other answers (such as the one from [Alex)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1282151/alex) also cover some details of the solution but are limited to `checking` the `name` as part of the condition. What would be ideal is to have a generalized solution that can work for any `String` field not just for checking the `name`.

There are two parts of your code that you need to abstract out :

1. The condition that must be satisfied inorder to perform an operation
2. The operation to perform when the condition is satisfied

This is what you can do :

```
public abstract class Parent {

   public final void doSomething(String str) {
        if(getCondition(str)) {
            doSomethingOnCondition(str);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("some thing");
        }
    }

    protected abstract boolean getCondition(String str);

    protected abstract void doSomethingOnCondition(String str);


}


class Child1 extends Parent {

    public static final String NAME = "CHILD1";

    @Override
    protected void doSomethingOnCondition(String str) {
        System.out.println("doing something with "+str);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean getCondition(String str) {
        return NAME.equals(str);
    }
}
```

Client code can then simply call the `doSomething` method as follows :

```
parent.doSomething(str);
```

A couple of points to note :

1. We make `doSomething` `final` because that's the piece of code we don't want the subclasses to change. We make it `public` so that it is visible to client code.
2. We make `getCondtion` and `doSomethingOnCondition` `protected` so that they are visible only to the child classes and not the client code. We make them `abstract` so that the child classes can assemble the condition and the work to be done after the condition is satisfied.
3. With generics, you can extend your solution to work for any
   data-type rather than just `String`. All you have to do is introduce
   a `type-parameter` in `Parent`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. On the parent add:

```
protected void checkNameEquality(String str) {
          //check input validity:
    if (!getNameForClass().equals(str)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("some thing");
    }
```

}

and on each child call

```
checkNameEquality(str);
```

To access the static name you need to add another abstract method to get the name for that class.

```
abstract String getnameForClass();
```

and implement it in each child.

There is no way to FORCE an implementor to make that check, but you only have to write the code once.

Comment: What will be `NAME` in your parent class's method?

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your abstract class with the common implementation and call the custom (overridden) implementation from there:

```
public abstract class Parent {
    public final boolean checkName(String str) {
        if (!getName().equals(str)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("some thing");
        }

        return _checkName(str);
    }

    public abstract boolean _checkName(String str);

    public abstract String getName();
}


public class Child1 extends Parent {

    public static final String NAME = "CHILD1";

    @Override
    public boolean _checkName(String str) {
        //...
    }

    public String getName() {
        return NAME;
    }
}


public class Child2 extends Parent {

    public static final String NAME = "CHILD2";

    @Override
    public boolean _checkName(String str) {
        // ...
    }

    public String getName() {
        return NAME;
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you can also call parent's checkName from the child methods.

Comment: How `NAME` will be resolved in your parent class concrete method?

Comment: I think you need `if (!getName().equals(str)) {`

Comment: What happens when a child class now want's to apply a condition on `age` rather than `name`? In other words, this solution is limited to a check on the `name` field.